# Does Support Libraries compiled into my app?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-support-library, android-appcompat

I m looking at **build.grade** and inside the dependencies i see:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:10.2.1'
```

Does that mean that those two libraries (and their code) will be integrated into my app?
is there a possibility that those libraries are ALREADY compiled on my device for all apps to use?

My thinking was that since almost every app uses appcompat-v7 and probably some of the play-services, than maybe Android Studio only compile them for developing purposes but forget about them when deploy to device and trust the device\framework (i am still learning the terms) to have them compiled and ready to use?
wouldn't it make since to have support libraries alreay compiled on the devices for all apps to use? (maybe like a DLL file)

please help me wrap my head around those concepts and mechanisms of what is going on

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does that mean that those two libraries (and their code) will be integrated into my app?

Yes.

> is there a possibility that those libraries are ALREADY compiled on my device for all apps to use?

No, though bear in mind that the Play Services library mostly is an API for talking to the Play Services Framework, which is a separate app on the device.

> wouldn't it make since to have support libraries alreay compiled on the devices for all apps to use? (maybe like a DLL file)

[That approach has issues](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DLL_Hell). The things that are part of the Android framework (i.e., stuff that does not require a library) behaves more or less as you describe. Things that are in libraries specifically do not behave that way, so different apps can use different versions.